# How to set default view for Robo3T?

Tags: robo3t

When using Robo3T(v1.3 OSX) to view documents, the default result view is in Tree mode. How do I change the default view to Table mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top Apple menu bar > Options > Default View Mode > The one you want to use